# Efficient quadratic optimization with simple linear constraint MatLab using CVX

Tags: matlab, quadratic-programming, cvx

(Sorry about formatting, I will try my best)  I want to solve:

```
x = argmin_x (Ax - p)'(Ax - p)
s.t. x >= b
```

where `A` is a `NxH` logical matrix (roughly half zeros, half ones), `b` is a `Hx1` constant vector where every entry is the same (e.g., `b = (0.1,0.1,0.1,...)`.  `p` is a constant `Nx1` vector of probabilities, so all entries are in `[0,1]`.  Optimal `x` is a distribution as well, so all of its entries should be in `[0,1]`.  Note that,in practice `H` is very large, e.g. `2 million` and `N` is relatively small, e.g. `150`.

I am currently using CVX to solve this.  Explicitly, my code is:

```
b= 0.1.*ones(H,1)/H;
cvx_begin quiet
    variable x(H)
    minimize( norm((A*x-p),2)) 
    subject to
       x >= b;
cvx_end
```

This produces the correct result.  However, it is fairly slow when `H` is large.  Given the structure of my optimization program (logical A, constant constraint, problem that has an analytical solution IF there were no constraint, ect), is there a better way to approach this?  Is CVX recommended here?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have the Optimization Toolbox, you can use [quadprog](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html).

Comment: The CVX page has an example on [bound-constrained least-squares](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/quickstart.html).